# get() returned more than one-- Django Restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model which needs to have more than 1 images and more than 1 files (numbers may vary as per requirement), for which I adjusted my Admin Panel accordingly like this

models.py

```
class MasterIndividualMembers(models.Model):
    individualmemberId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100, default=1)
    ...
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname

class IndividualMemberPhotos(models.Model):
    individualmemberId = models.ForeignKey(MasterIndividualMembers, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="individualmemberphotos/")


class IndividualMemberCatalogue(models.Model):
    individualmemberId = models.ForeignKey(MasterIndividualMembers, default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to="individualmembercatalogue/")
```

admin.py

```
class IndividualMemberPhotosAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = IndividualMemberPhotos

class IndividualMemberCatalogueAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = IndividualMemberCatalogue

@admin.register(MasterIndividualMembers)
class MasterIndividualMembersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [IndividualMemberPhotosAdmin,IndividualMemberCatalogueAdmin]
 
    class Meta:
       model = MasterIndividualMembers
```

For the views I simply make a function to provide details of all the Images, Document and that User

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def get_individualmember(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            individualmemberId = request.POST.get('individualmemberId')
            result = {}
            result['individualMemberDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', [MasterIndividualMembers.objects.get(individualmemberId=individualmemberId)]))
            result['individualPhotoDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', IndividualMemberPhotos.objects.filter(individualmemberId__individualmemberId = individualmemberId)))
            result['individualCatalogueDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json', IndividualMemberCatalogue.objects.filter(individualmemberId__individualmemberId = individualmemberId)))
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(e)
```

**Problem:** While fetching the details for any individual member, it throws an error `get() returned more than one IndividualMemberPhotos -- it returned 2!`, which is expected to have more than 1 objects.

How can I make the Restframework to provide me details of all image object together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `get()` which strictly returns a single element, use `filter()` which returns 0 or more elements.

As documented in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object
> matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a
> single element.
>
> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can
> use the get() method on a Manager which returns the object directly:

The behavior you are experiencing is actually documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get

> If get() finds more than one object, it raises a
> Model.MultipleObjectsReturned exception: